# Pyqt hyperlink not launching external application

Tags: python, qt, hyperlink, pyqt, qtextedit

So i have a QTextEdit and i put some html hyperlink to a local file in it like this :

```
<a href="file:\\path\\to\\myfile">link</a>
```

When i launch my application, Qt puts my link in blue but it doesn't show the little hand and i can't click on it.

Before you throw rocks at me :

- I checked that my file really exists of course
- I tried using a QTextBrowser instead, the hand shows up but when i click on it, my cursors spins for a long time and and the app eventually opens the file binaries in my QTextBrowser
- i set up the interaction flags `self.workflow_log_textedit.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.LinksAccessibleByKeyboard|QtCore.Qt.LinksAccessibleByMouse|QtCore.Qt.TextBrowserInteraction|QtCore.Qt.TextEditable|QtCore.Qt.TextEditorInteraction|QtCore.Qt.TextSelectableByKeyboard|QtCore.Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)`
- I tried putting 3 slashes between "file" and the path like this `<a href="file:///\\path\\to\\myfile">link</a>`, this just clears my QTextBrowser when i click it
- I tried adding `type="image"` and `target="_blank"` in my hyperlink, same result

I want to point out that it doesn't work any better with http links

EDIT :
MCVE as requested :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

import sys

class MyMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tb = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
        self.tb.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.LinksAccessibleByKeyboard|QtCore.Qt.LinksAccessibleByMouse|QtCore.Qt.TextBrowserInteraction|QtCore.Qt.TextEditable|QtCore.Qt.TextEditorInteraction|QtCore.Qt.TextSelectableByKeyboard|QtCore.Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)
        self.tb.setHtml('<a target="_blank" href="file:///{path}">{path}</a>'.format(path='C:\Users\johndoe\Pictures\doge.png'))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tb) 

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
foo = MyMainWindow()
foo.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I added the mcve you requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example will work fine if you set the url to an html document. But it won't work if you set it to an image file, for the same reason it wouldn't if you tried to open an image file in a text-editor. The `QTextEdit` and `QTextBrowser` classes can handle plain text, plus a [limited subset of HTML4](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html) - and that's all.

Of course, you can use `<img>` tags to display images inside an html document. So something like the following should work:

```
self.tb.setHtml('<img src="image.png" />')
```

of for an image hyperlink:

```
self.tb.setHtml('<a href="doc.html"><img src="image.png" /></a>')
```